# How to change layout of icon-image on hover in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use GeoJson Mapbox, and I want to change "icon-image" on hover.

```
map.addLayer({
"id": "points",
"type": "symbol",
"source": {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": "geo.json"
},
"layout": {
"icon-image": "icon-1"
});
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change any layout property, including `icon-image`, with `setLayoutProperty`:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('points', 'icon-image', 'icon-2');
```